# Browser console shows CORS error regardless of the type of error that happens on the server side of a fastapi app

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, rest, fastapi

I have fastapi app that is running on the same server as a react app.

I make a simple, async request to the route, but regardless of the type of error that happens on the server (syntaxerror, valueerror, etc...), the browser console shows a CORS error

I am 100% positive it is not a cors error

How can I make it display more accurate errors on the frontend?

Comment: Are your error pages sending the correct CORS headers..?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I've followed the standard way to allow all origins to access a fastapi app, so I know it's not a CORS error

Comment: Any access control header will NOT be included in any error response, which will effectively give you a CORS error in the browser. The server side error can never be a CORS error as that's a pure client side error, but since the header(s) doesn't get included on error responses, that's what your browser will say.

Comment: how to I modify the headers then in fastapi?

Comment: does allowing all origins not pass the correct headers by default?

Comment: Depending on the error, it could be sent by the webserver and not the application framework. Check your server logs.

Comment: I'm using gunicorn for the webserver, what would I check the logs for? I see the python syntax error, but nothing about cors

Comment: A syntax error will likely be converted to a 500 error on the server. The 500 response does not contain any CORS headers, and the browser will signal a cors error. Fix your syntax error and the cors error will go away.

Comment: yes, I know that. I wanted to know in my original question if there is a way to get a more accurate error, because a 500 error is not a cors error

Comment: The answer to that is no. At least unless you set cors headers in gunicorn/nginx/whatever is outmost in your stack.

Comment: i would like to look into it, but searching for  "gunicorn set cors headers" doesn't yield anything

Comment: would you share your code and your error ?